# Jfrog Artifactory OSS advantages over Bitnami Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: java

Can anyone explain the advantages of using Jfrog OSS over the Bitnami Jfrog Artifactory
I am looking for external postgresql,HA ,connected to Azure AD and cost factor